# Need to customize the top menu in woothemes canvas, depending if the user is logged in or not I need to show 1 menu instead of the other

Tags: php, wordpress, canvas, hook, navigationbar

I've already created a canvas child-theme. I added my custom page woo-hooks.class.php in the canvas-child folder in which i copied all the code from the original and added here:

```
$this->hooks['header'] = array(
        'woo_top' => array(
        'content' => '',
        'shortcodes' => 0,
        'php' =>'
```

the following code:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_nav_menu( array( "theme_location" => "top-menu-loggedin" ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( "theme_location" => "top-menu-loggedout" ) );
}
```

the code is like it doesn't even exists, I know I've probably mistaken what I have to do, but i couldn't find a clear guide anywhere on how to do this, just some code in some forums with no context about how and where to act (the code i added I found it in a forum, but I guess i didn't add it in the right place). The filter and hooks guides of WP don't make clear WHERE and HOW to call the custom filters and hooks and how to actually make them interact with the existing code... I'm going nuts, please help.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/ this plugin solves the problem and even adds personalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top menu customization can be performed in header section, that is in child theme's 'header.php' file or in other file, specifying 'theme-location' parameter.

You can write below code, in your child theme,

```
if (is_user_logged_in()){
   wp_nav_menu(array( 
  'menu_class' => 'member-menu',
  'menu'  => 'Members',
  'theme_location'  => 'primary');
   );
}else{
      wp_nav_menu(array( 
     'menu_class' => 'top-menu',
     'menu'  => 'Members non Logged in',
     'theme_location'  => 'primary')
     );
 }
```

Here, 'theme-location' parameter is specifies location of Menu and 'menu' specifies name of Menu.

Comment: Ok, I changed menu_class in both cases to top-menu, in menu i put the names of my 2 menus, in theme location i put top. But i need you to clarify to me where i should put this code: 
I tried in header.php in a few locations but everytime it loads a blank page. I tried in woo-hooks.class.php both in header hook and nav hook, they both ignore the code.